# What's the best way to write an ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net

At one extreme, you could generate every possible page of your website via a single aspx page by passing in all sorts of parameters on the url, put a big switch statement in the code behind, and generate all the output via the single page.

At the opposite extreme, you could create dozens of static pages and very little code in any code behind file.

Another choice one must make when generating a website via ASP.NET is setting properties on controls. Do you do this via the Visual Studio gui and the properties window, or do you do it programatically?

There are lots of ways to skin a cat. My personal preference to create aspx pages covering all the things my site needs to do, then generate the output (and set properties) programatically. Many times, if a single page has a couple similar uses, I'll use one page to generate multiple kinds of output based on a parameter I pass to it via the url.

I'm interested in hearing how other folks do it.

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: As usual with this sort of question, it entirely depends on what you are trying to do.  Usually product managers / designers have no trouble using unique URLs (pages) as the delineating point in their specs.  Also, there's no reason to think that you won't get all the code re-use you desire using separate pages, so most likely your implementation will be pretty far from either theoretical extreme.  Incidentally, a solution based purely on static pages would never work for truly dynamic data such as from databases.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Too bad there wasn't a chance for more!

Comment: Maybe one of the people who voted to close this question because it was "subjective and argumentative" could provide some other good sources for answers to my question.

Answer (score 1):

For a totally dynamic site I'd go with using or implementing some kind of CMS.

For 'brochureware' sites that are design heavy with little content that changes we go with basic ASP.Net project using Master pages/themes etc.

Somewhere between the two (the majority of what we do) we encapsulate functionality (e.g. reusable components) into User/Custom controls.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Too bad there wasn't a chance for more!